# Rstudio server in a (firefox) browser: confict between shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, rstudio-server

I am using Rstudio Server from within Firefox. This allows me to run Rstudio as if I was using its desktop version. A key difference is that there is now a conflict between Rstudio definition of shortcuts, and firefox ones:

- Both have open (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>), save (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>) but Rstudio takes precedence
- Both have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, but here firefox (or the System, one?) takes precedence (meaning I am closing the whole firefox window, not Rstudio tab)
- Switch tab shortcut will switch firefox tabs, not rstudio tabs

How does precedence works? And how should I do if I wanted that when I am in rstudio in a firefox tab, switch tab switches among rstudio tabs? This is discussed a little [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-keys-conflicting-with-browser-in-rstudio-server/8870/3) but no good solution offered so far. I am using Ubuntu if this plays a role...

Thanks!

Comment: Same problem. Have you found a solution ?

Comment: no :-( And still avid to find one. Probably need to ask on Rstudio forum